# Global.Asax error in MVC4 Web API runnin in Azure compute emulator - only sometimes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I noticed yesterday that this error was happening in my local Windows Azure emulator when I debugged my web role. But the deployed project still worked on Azure. Today, my deployed project is failing with this same error. HELP PLEASE!

This code block in my Global.axax.cs file's Application_Start method:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers
  .Add(new BasicAuthMessageHandler()
  {
     PrincipalProvider = new PrincipalProvider()
  });
```

throws this error:

Inheritance security rules violated by type: 'System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonContractResolver'. Derived types must either match the security accessibility of the base type or be less accessible.

when I start debugging (this is an Azure web role project). But only sometimes (actually it seems to happen every OTHER time I debug) ... and all I have to do to fix it is to stop and re-start the debugger. What is causing the problem?

Comment: what is "MVC4 Web API emulator"?

Comment: Good question - sorry - I mean running locally in the debugger. I have an Azure web role and the debugger runs the Azure compute emulator.

Comment: I ran into this problem myself. It only occurred when the ASP.NET project referenced a portable class library which then referenced Json.Net. I spent a whole day messing around with no success, I ended up fixing it by making the library not a portable class library so I could get a different version of Json.Net. I never got to the bottom of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This had something to do with the Newtonsoft.Json assembly. I deleted it from my project's references, cleaned and rebuilt the project (for good measure), and then re-added it and rebuilt the project again. The error went away.

System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonContractResolver is derived from Newtonsoft.Json. Another thread (here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1812274.aspx/3/10) addressed this same problem by removing Newtonsoft.Json from the GAC, since it was there and System.Net.Http.Formatting was not. This apparently solved a person's problem, although it seems backward to me (why can't the base type be in the GAC while the derived type is not? Isn't the error saying the problem is the other way around??).

Comment: This is a recurring problem for me - it will go away if I do a clean build but as soon as I attempt to debug then it comes back again. It seems to be related to adding a PCL as a dependency of my WebAPI project.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your nuget packages.  I updated mine, and it fixed the issue.  I was also having this issue on azure service itself.